# planar curve has infinitely many Bertrand mates

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Show that a planar curve has infinitely many Bertrand mates.

Can anyone give hints or direction on how to prove this? Thanks

Comment: Your question "Show q(t,ϕ) defines a parametrized surface" seemed good to me.  Why did you delete it?

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. Should I have not deleted but instead answered it myself?

Comment: I think that would be cool.  To my mind it is a good question; I had halfway worked out an answer when you deleted it!  I for one would like to see what you've got.  Note that there's even a check box on the "ASK" page for answering your own question and sharing what you know.  Of course, it's up to you . . . Cheers!

Comment: Note that there's no policy or rule that says you have to delete a question just because you've figured out the answer.  Also, other MSE users might like to see what you've got.  More Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A parallel Bertrand curve is obtained by erecting a normal of constant length at each point on a curve C. Any smooth continuous curve C is a set of infinite connected points, so correspondingly there are infinitely many curved parallels.